# API call failed : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found Exception while changing Data Source of Spring Boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, properties

I would like to change my data source from mariah DB to oracle 9i database .

When it comes to the execution, it gives the following exception. Do I need to modify my repository and model connecting to this database?

Error:

```
2019-11-08 12:29:04.011  INFO 16044 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2019-11-08 12:29:04.013  INFO 16044 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-11-08 12:29:04.160  INFO 16044 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-11-08 12:29:04.356  INFO 16044 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect
```

application.properties

```
// Server Port
server.port=4200

spring.datasource.url =jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:dev
spring.datasource.username =ops$dev
spring.datasource.password =abc123sss
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database-platform= org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = true
```

And then, my screen tells Unable to connect instead of giving out string messages :

[image]

Comment: That is not an error, but a just `[INFO]`.  You may have to change your PK using something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/1791368/643500

Comment: It is fine if you are not using hibernate.properties https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558028/spring-data-configuration-hibernate-properties-not-found

Comment: But that comes another question: Why my localhost cannot connect to the Spring boot?

Comment: Open a new question and add the relevant information.  Try default 8080